# Mail goes to Outlook spam folder

Tags: c#, email, outlook, spamassassin

When I want to send message to outlook.com e-mail address, then it's going to spam/junk folder, while it's OK for Google and Yahoo mail. I've checked SpamAssassin scores for all these mail providers (I've used https://spamcheck.postmarkapp.com/):

1. Google: 1.7, Good
   1.5 RCVD_IN_SORBS_WEB (I'm on one blacklist)
2. Yahoo: 1.5, Good
   1.5 RCVD_IN_SORBS_WEB (the same - I'm on one blacklist. The rest is OK!)
3. Outlook: 5.7, Spam!

   > 0.0 URIBL_BLOCKED          ADMINISTRATOR NOTICE: The query to URIBL was
   >                               blocked. See
   >                               http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/DnsBlocklists…
   >                               #dnsbl-block for more information. [URIs:x]
   >    1.2 MISSING_HEADERS        Missing To: header
   >    0.1 DKIM_SIGNED            Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not
   >                               necessarily valid
   >    0.1 DKIM_INVALID           DKIM or DK signature exists, but is not valid
   >    0.0 UNPARSEABLE_RELAY      Informational: message has unparseable relay lines
   >    1.4 MISSING_DATE           Missing Date: header
   >    1.0 MISSING_FROM           Missing From: header
   >    0.1 MISSING_MID            Missing Message-Id: header
   >    1.8 MISSING_SUBJECT        Missing Subject: header
   >    0.0 TVD_SPACE_RATIO        No description available.
4. GMX: 4, Good (well, it's in spam folder!)

> -0.0 RCVD_IN_DNSWL_NONE     RBL: Sender listed at https://www.dnswl.org/, no
>                               trust [ listed in list.dnswl.org]
>    0.1 DKIM_SIGNED            Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not
>                               necessarily valid
>    0.1 DKIM_INVALID           DKIM or DK signature exists, but is not valid
>    1.3 RDNS_NONE              Delivered to internal network by a host with no
>                               rDNS
>    2.3 EMPTY_MESSAGE          Message appears to have no textual parts and no
>                               Subject: text
>    0.1 MISSING_MID            Missing Message-Id: header

As you can see there're missing headers, but it was OK in Google and Yahoo. Here is my code (C#)

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(username, mailReceiver);
mail.Subject = title;
AddAlternativeTextViewToMail(ref mail, message); // adding alternative view to HTML one (plain text)

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Port = 587;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Host = "mail.mydomain.com";
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
//mail.Body = message; // no body, coz it's already in alternative view

client.Send(mail);
```

Here is AddAlternativeTextViewToMail method:

```
private static void AddAlternativeTextViewToMail(ref MailMessage mail, string message)
        {
            string htmlTagPattern = "<[^\"]*?>";
            string plainMessage = message.Replace("<br />", "\r\n");
            plainMessage = Regex.Replace(plainMessage, htmlTagPattern, string.Empty);
            plainMessage = plainMessage.Replace("<", "").Replace(">", "").Replace("a target=\"_blank\" href=\"", " ").Replace("\"", " ").Replace("a href=", "");
            //plainMessage = Regex.Replace(plainMessage, @"^\s+$[\r\n]*", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
            //plainMessage = plainMessage.Replace(" ", string.Empty);

            mail.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(plainMessage, Encoding.UTF8, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain));
            mail.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(message, Encoding.UTF8, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Html));
        }
```

Also if I send the same e-mail from Google mail, then it is not going to spam folder in Outlook. What am I doing wrong?
Cheers

Comment: This is really out of scope for SO.. As this is more about why mail systems treat something as spam. However the 2 key parts that have most weight are the reverse dns isnt available, and the fact you provided a HTML body and no textual body. Fix those it probably wont go in spam, however,  the more mails you send that match spam criteria more companies will flag you as spamming

Comment: I've provided 2 alternative views: HTML and plain text